# Convert coordinates to address

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, coordinates

I want to know how you convert geo coordinates into an address. I have already tried the `CLGeocoder` class but I have no idea how to convert my data.

Thanks

Comment: Did you search for sample code? Did you read the doc? What did you tried with `GLGeocoder`? What went wrong?

Comment: I have used the CLGeocoder class to convert my address into coordinates. But I have no idea how to use the class for converting coordinates into an address

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the CLGeocoder Class to get a coordinate to physical address lookup. The command you are looking for is `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:`. You pass your CLLocation location object containing the coordinate data to look up.

Read more about it in Apple's [CLGeocoder Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder).